# Need correct PHP output in Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, html

How to correctly print the result of the php code in Sublime Text 3?
My code is:

```
<?php

   $nums = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10');

   echo "<table><tr>";

   foreach($nums as $i) {

     foreach($nums as $j)
         echo "<td>".($i*$j)."</td>";   

      if ($i != 10) echo "</tr><tr>";

   };

  echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Output:
[image: output]
Hope that it can be possible to get the result in console like this ([from here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/))
[image: expected result]
Maybe I should use another syntax instead of `<tr></tr> <td></td> <table></table>`? Thanks for watching!

Comment: Do you have php installed? Your code works just fine by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sublime you can only see the output of a PHP script as text.

To render the output like you showed in the example you will need to use a browser.

To do this you will need a local http server.

Use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html). (works on both Windows and Linux)

Steps to make it work:

- install xampp
- move your project into xampp_install_location/htdocs/your_project/
- start the xampp server either by using the interface on windows or from the cli in linux
- open a browser and go to `http://localhost/your_project/filename.php`

Comment: Thanks, it works fine, but really there isn't any way to get a result in Sublime?

Comment: Sublime is a smart text editor, not a browser. It can't render HTML. Even if you find a plugin that does that I would recommend you use a browser.